# UIPickerView connections

Tags: interface-builder, connection, uipicker, uipickerviewcontroller

I'm having a problem with the connections of UIPickerView.
My viewController class looks like this:

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;/this is what it says in all tutorials
//other textfields
}
 @property..of textfields, label, nsstring
@end
```

In the interface builder, when i ctrl+click on the file's owner, my pickerview appears in Outlets and NOT in referencing outlets(against what is shown in tutorial).
How do I make the connections? and what do I connect it to?
I want the PickerView to be displayed on click of a button whose action is also registered in the above class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just have a misunderstanding. I created a class similar to what you described:

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    UIPickerView *pickerView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;

Then I opened up the xib. I right-clicked on the File's Owner (or cmd-click if you don't have a two button mouse), which brought up a list of all of the Outlets on MyViewController. I find this a lot easier than the ctrl-clicking that most of the tutorials suggest you do. Then I clicked and dragged from the circle next to pickerView down to the pickerView. Let go of the mouse button and it connects just fine.

[image: Interface Builder screenshot]